# Currency Validation with $ and , in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have this model object defined below with currency validation, using **jQuery validator** plugin

```
Model Item
{
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$", 
           ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid money value. 2 Decimals only allowed")]
        public decimal? Price{ get; set; }
}
```

But when I enter `$165,600.70` I am getting `Enter a valid money value. 2 Decimals only allowed.` It is a valid input from user point.

However if they enter `165640.73 it is working`.

How do i have this regex to work for both? Any help on rewrite this regex?

**Rendered HTML**

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." 
data-val-regex="Enter a valid money value. 2 Decimals only allowed" 
data-val-regex-pattern="^\$?-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$" id="Price" name="Price" 
type="text" value="$165,600.70">
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including `$` in your regex . Perhaps you want something like this.

```
 ^\$?-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
  ^^^ Add these 3
```

Comment: Added your code now. Still it is not working. Please see the rendered HTML i posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\$-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

- You have to use the $ (add a ? after if you want it optional)
- You have to use the ,
- I took the liberty to make the decimals optional and forbidding only 1 decimal (doesn't make much sense for currency)

**Edit:**

```
^\$-?\d{1,3}(?:(,?)\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

Here you do, commas are optional.

Comment: How about `^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$` which i found from http://regexlib.com

Comment: Your reg ex fails for `165640.73` value :(

Comment: Well, I did stated that you have to use the ,. I'm changing it so you don't need to.

Comment: @Murali See my edit. I think you may want whitespaces too but you could easily change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
^\$-?\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

1-3 digits followed by an arbitrary number of either single digits (i.e. no commas) or groupings of `,<three digits>` with an optional `.<1-2 digits>` at the end. I would agree as others have suggested that a single decimal when working with currencies is confusing, so you might want to change `{1,2}` to `{2}`.